How to amalgamate/collapse rows after using keyword 'by'?
I have a certain dataset that I have selected as below:
tbl: select qtix by name, ptype from data

Which yields the following result:
| name | ptype | qtix | 
-----------------------
| ABCD | `BLUE | 132  |
| PQRS | `BLUE | 140  |
| PQRS | `RED  | 260  |
| VXYZ | `BLUE | 116  |
...

I have done so as this dataset is to be filtered based on ptype later on but for now I am wanting to put it back together such that name is the only distinct field, i.e.:
| name |    ptype    | qtix | 
-----------------------------
| ABCD | `BLUE       | 132  |
| PQRS | `BLUE`RED   | 400  |
| VXYZ | `BLUE       | 116  |
...

I have attempted to do this via:
tbl: select by name from tbl
But instead this only chooses one of the two rows to display instead of joining them together, however I am unsure how to perform a join on a row basis instead of for columns.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You can use the keyword ungroup. (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/ungroup/)
q)show tbl:([] name:`a`c`c`a; ptype:`blue`blue`red`blue; qtix:4?10)
name ptype qtix
---------------
a    blue  7
c    blue  1
c    red   9
a    blue  1
q)show tbl:select qtix by name,ptype from tbl
name ptype| qtix
----------| ----
a    blue | 7 1
c    blue | ,1
c    red  | ,9
q)show tbl:ungroup tbl
name ptype qtix
---------------
a    blue  7
a    blue  1
c    blue  1
c    red   9
q)show tbl:select ptype,qtix by name from tbl
name| ptype     qtix
----| --------------
a   | blue blue 7 1
c   | blue red  1 9
q)show tbl:ungroup tbl
name ptype qtix
---------------
a    blue  7
a    blue  1
c    blue  1
c    red   9

Do note that (from the docs):
ungroup is not the exact inverse of grouping
Grouping sorts on the keys, so a subsequent ungroup returns the original records sorted by the grouped column/s.
Also note that if you do:
tbl: select by name from tbl

You are only selecting the last entry of the name.
